# How can i test multiple queries result with phpunit

Tags: php, mysql, nested, phpunit

I am a bit new in phpunit, after hours of researching I am not quite find a way.  How can I test function getResults using phpunit.

the function getResults and getResultsDetails belong to Result class.  Function searchUser belong to User class.  To get pass login I could do invoke doLogin in Login object with username and password and it will remain in $_SESSION

```
class Result {      
   public function __construct()
   {
       if(!isset($_SESSION)){
           session_start();
       }
       $this->loginObject = new Login();
   }

   public function getResults($fName, $lName)
   {
       $result = searchUser($fName, $lName);
       while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
          $userIDs = $result['id'] . ',';
       }
       return 
         array(
        'userIDs' => $userIDs,
        'count'   => getResultDetails($userIDs),
        'results' => getResultDetails($userIDs, 0, 500),
        )
   }
```

If limit and offset being pass in then return the result, otherwise return count for everything

```
   public function getResultDetails($userIDs, $limit = null, $offset =null)
   {
       if(!$this->beforeFilter()) return "logout";
       //open db connection
       $sql = '';
       if(!$limit && !$offset)
       {
          $sql .= 'SELECT count(*) ';
       } else {
         $sql .= 'SELECT a.info, b.info, d.info ';
       }

       $sql .= 'FROM a ';
       $sql .= 'inner join b on blah blah';
       $sql .= 'inner join d blah blah';
       $sql .= "where d.userID in ($userIDs)";    
       if($limit && $offset)
         $sql .= "LIMIT $limit, $offset";

       return mysql_query($sql);
     }
  }
```

This is the search forUser base on firName and lastName.  searchUser belong to User class
    class Patient{
       public function __construct()
       {
           if(!isset($_SESSION)){
               session_start();
           }
           $this->loginObject = new Login();
       }

```
   public function searchUser($fName, $lName)
   {
        if(!$this->beforeFilter()) return "logout";
        // logic to do search user and return user result mysq_query($sql)
        return userIDs;
   } 

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use stub/mock for this. Basically you don't want test searchUser nor getResultDetails methods in getResult method unit test. So you have to mock them and just check if they've called with appropriate arguments.

You will use phpunit mock for that.

First step is set any expected values and build mock:

```
$someExpectedUser = 123;
$expectedCount = 234;
$expectedResult = array('blablabla');

$object = $this->getMock('YourTestedClass', array('searchUser', 'getResultDetails'));
```

You've created mock object now. First argument is name of your class and second is array with names of methods that you want mock (pay attention that you don't specify "getResult" method in second argument - this means when you call this method on $object - the real one will be called).

The next step is specify behaviour of searchUser:

```
$object->expects($this->once())
    ->method('searchUser')
    ->with($fName, $lName)
    ->will($this->returnValue($someExpectedUser));
```

The same for getResultDetails method:

```
$object->expects($this->at(1))
    ->method('getResultDetails')
    ->with($someExpectedUser)
    ->will($this->returnValue($expecedCount));

$object->expects($this->at(2))
    ->method('getResultDetails')
    ->with($someExpectedUser, 0, 500)
    ->will($this->returnValue($expecedResults));
```

Then all you need is call tested method and check if it returns expeced value:

```
$expectedResult = array(
    'userIDs' => $someExpectedUser,
    'count'   => $expectedCount,
    'results' => $expectedResult
);
$result = $object->getResult($fName, $lName);
$this->assertEquals($expectedResult, $result);
```

Please let me know if something is not clear for you.

Greetings!

Comment: Your comment is really helpful. I did make some change on my original question. But when I do $userObj = $this->getMock('Users', array('doLogin', 'searchUser')); $userObj->expects($this->once()) ->method('doLogin') ->with('username', 'password'); I get Expectation failed for method name is equal to <string:doLogin> when invoked 1 time(s).
Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times.

Comment: Yes - because you specified that doLogin should be called exatcly once ($this->once() - tells your mock that this method should be executed no more no less but exactly one time) - but you never call it (at least I can't see it based on your posted code).